# How do I changed this Firebase version 8 syntax to version 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This is the syntax I originally used to add a document to a subcollection "posts". But I think it is not supported by firebase version 9

```js
const unsubscribe = db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email).collection("posts").add({
  imageUrl: currentLoggedInUser.unsername,
  user: CurrentLoggedInUser.username,
  profile_picture: CurrentLoggedInUser.profilePicture,
  owner_uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
  caption: caption,
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  likes: 0,
  likes_by_users: [],
  comments: [],
}).then(() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen'))
return unsubscribe
```

What I tried

```js
const unsubscribe = (doc(collection(db, "users")), auth.currentUser.email, addDoc(collection("posts"), {
  imageUrl: imageUrl,
  user: CurrentLoggedInUser.username,
  profile_picture: CurrentLoggedInUser.profilePicture,
  owner_uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
  caption: caption,
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  likes: 0,
  likes_by_users: [],
  comments: [],
}).then(() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen'))
return unsubscribe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things become much more readable if you capture the result of some of these operations in a meaningfully named variable.

```
const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
const userRef = doc(usersRef, auth.currentUser.email);
const postsRef = collection(userRef, "posts");
const promise = addDoc(postsRef, {
  imageUrl: imageUrl,
  user: CurrentLoggedInUser.username,
  profile_picture: CurrentLoggedInUser.profilePicture,
  owner_uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
  caption: caption,
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  likes: 0,
  likes_by_users: [],
  comments: [],
});
return promise.then(() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen'));
```

Once the above works, you can rewrite the first three lines to:

```
const postsRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.email, "posts");
```

Comment: It is still giving me an error => "  An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field user in document users/lover42cherry@gmail.com/posts/swOKk71wuDWxHUJwTMmh)] "

Comment: Thanks. This syntax is way better than mine.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just saw the problem two of the docs passed through promise to "posts" were undefined: user & profile_picture